# Woocommerce: menu products (wp-admin) visible for all users

Tags: list, listview, menu, woocommerce, product

I would like to enable access to the administration menu of products not only to superadmin but to other users: author, editor, customer and shop managers so that they too can enter the products in the database woocommerce.

At the moment the administration screen / wp-admin menu appears woocomerce products. How can I then enable it for all users?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend taking a look at [User Role Editor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/) to accomplish this. You can add/edit/remove capabilities to each role.